# bullet points in view

Tags: views, blocks

I created a block-view which shows me the titles of the newest content. By default drupal simply lists the titles. I would like that the list appears with bullet points. Is this only possible to do in CSS? Is there no way to format it in the view module?

Thanks for any feedback

Answer (score 6):

In the settings of your view, change the format from "Unformatted list" to "HTML list".

Comment: This is the current configuration. In settings I have list type= ordered list and wrapper class is "item-list". Somebody just told me, that the theme I am using has removed bullets by default... I investigate this now.